Does the hose need to be changed?


Car is a Honda civic vti coupe 1999.
I tried to see if I could force in an oversized battery into battery bay and due to this I seem
To have damaged this hose(I think it’s a coolant hose as it goes to the engine). You can see the battery is removed and the hose in front has tears/damage.
I do not see any leaks(at least not yet).
Will this hose wear away quickly/possibly leaking coolant without me knowing in which case should I change it asap or is it only superficial and unlikely to get worse so i can just leave as is.
Thanks.

Whatever that is, it's not a coolant line. You say it connects to the engine, what does the other end connect to? I'm betting it's not to anything coolant related.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 sorry I’ve attached another pic.  You can see the empty battery bay and the hose infront which goes looks like it’s going to the engine and I’d assume it’s part engine cooling.

That's an AC line, not engine cooling. The cover which you've damaged is just a protection for the AC line. This protection also keeps the AC line insulated so it will help with AC performance. Your little bit of rub you've put on this insulation isn't anything to be afraid of. You've not done anything major to the AC line or its insulation.
